# Connecting paragraphs in comparative analysis

Tags: text-analysis

I have been asked to write an essay in which I have to provide an opinion on a target text while viewing it from the perspective of another text (the lens text). (The target and lens text provides two different sides of a debate).

The pattern goes as follows:

Introduction of the topic on which target text is centered.

Identify a possible hole in the target text

Introduce the lens text

Thesis

Explain why lens text fills that whole

Introduce the arguments of the target and respond it via the lens.

The problem I have is with connecting the last two items.
This is how my last two items go

**Furthermore, to affirm whether an argument holds true, A (lens' author) makes use of the ... (para 1)**

**The core idea of the argument of B (target's author) that followed, draws its roots from an assumption... (para 2)**

What sentence should I put after the first paragraph so as to connect it with the second paragraph? The reason I have such a request is because it feels like a discontinuity/jump in between the two paragraphs. So when a reader is reading the essay, the thought process goes like this, "Oh okay so that's the method lens text utilizes to argue... BAM! target text arguments. "
Can somebody please help me how to connect these paragraph?, and if there is an ambiguity in the question let me know.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me how your paragraphs create the BAM, because I  would want to read the source material and your essay to understand it best. But have you played with phrases such as: "Contrast this with the..." "On the other hand...." "This is particularly a problem in light of..." ... or other phrasing along these lines ...preceding 'The core idea...." ?

Comment: By BAM I meant the reader is confused since there is a jump.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Without seeing the whole piece, it is not clear to me why the reader would feel BAM. However, I am NOT suggesting that you share the piece. I suspect there may be a simple phrase you can add before 'The core idea...' to tell the reader not to feel BAM.

Answer (score 2):

I had a critical thinking instructor who liked the following format: summarize the target argument, logically extend the target argument, critically analyze the logical extension. A bridge sentence might begin: logically extended. . . . Without knowing more about context it's hard to assess applicability.